# Can use ejs template inside href attribute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
 <% list.forEach(b => { %>
       <tr>
            <td><%= b.no %></td>
            <td><a href="/board/b?no=<%=no%>"> <%= b.title %> </a></td>
            <td><%= b.writer %></td>
            <td><%= b.postdate %></td>
            <td><%= b.view%></td>
      </tr>
 <% }) %>
```

I wanted to pass the value of no to the node server, so I used ejs inside the href attribute but it does not work properly.

Please advise if this is wrong.

Comment: `no` not set but `b.no` is, is that what you meant. ie. typo. `/board/b?no=<%= b.no %>`

Comment: I changed that, but the result of console.log (req.params.no) is undefined on the server.

Comment: its in `req.query.no` :)

Comment: hold your horses.. is your express controller route `/board/:no` and you're wanting to pass in like: `href="/board/<%= b.no %>">`? either way it will be in params then

Comment: it works! Thanks~